# Azure AutoML dependency failure

Tags: conda, xgboost, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-auto-ml

**Issue** : Unable to get best model from AutoML run.

**Code:**

```
best_run, fitted_model = automl_run.get_output()
print(best_run.properties["run_algorithm"])
```

**Error Message :**

```
ErrorResponse 
[stderr]{
[stderr]    "error": {
[stderr]        "code": "UserError",
[stderr]        "message": "The model you attempted to retrieve requires 'xgboost' to be installed at '==1.3.3'. You have 'xgboost==1.3.3', please reinstall 'xgboost==1.3.3' (e.g. `pip install xgboost==1.3.3`) and rerun the previous command.",
[stderr]        "target": "get_output",
[stderr]        "inner_error": {
[stderr]            "code": "NotSupported",
[stderr]            "inner_error": {
[stderr]                "code": "IncompatibleOrMissingDependency"
[stderr]            }
[stderr]        },
[stderr]        "reference_code": "910310e6-2433-40cd-b597-9ec2950bc1d8"
[stderr]    }
```

**Conda Dependency**

```
# Conda environment specification. The dependencies defined in this file will
# be automatically provisioned for runs with userManagedDependencies=False.

# Details about the Conda environment file format:
# https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually

name: project_environment
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.
  # Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.
- python=3.6.12

- pip:
  - azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.38.0
  - azureml-train-automl-client==1.38.0
  - inference-schema
  - azureml-interpret==1.38.0
  - azureml-defaults==1.38.0
- numpy>=1.16.0,<1.19.0
- pandas==0.25.1
- scikit-learn==0.22.1
- py-xgboost<=1.3.3
- fbprophet==0.5
- holidays==0.9.11
- psutil>=5.2.2,<6.0.0
- matplotlib=3.3.2
- seaborn=0.9.0
- joblib=0.13.2
- joblib
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
```

**Question:**

- What should be in my conda dependency that can fix this error
- I've tried making `py-xgboost==1.3.3` , but it didn't work.
- Any luck - how to fix this ?

Comment: Please expand on "it didn't work," we need more information to help. What didn't work?

Comment: I tried changing dependency to 'py-xgboost==1.3.3' , but I got same error message as shown above.
Tried by updating to  
- py-xgboost<=1.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error - "The model you attempted to retrieve requires 'xgboost' to be
> installed at '==1.3.3'. You have 'xgboost==1.3.3', please reinstall
> 'xgboost==1.3.3' (e.g. `pip install xgboost==1.3.3`) and rerun the
> previous command."

As given in above error message, it should be `pip install xgboost==1.3.3` not `py-xgboost<=1.3.3`

If it does not work, try downgraded version of `xgboost`

```
pip install xgboost==0.90
```

Refer this github [link](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1421)

Comment: pip install xgboost==0.90 fixed the issue